# How to change splash screen in dark mode(Android)?

Tags: flutter, darkmode, android-darkmode

I created a simple project and added the `flutter_native_splash` package. I am running this project on my android phone via USB. If my phone is in light mode splash screen works fine. But in the dark mode, it did not work. So then I tried to add my splash screen image to `android/app/src/main/res/drawable-night` and it worked. The problem is when I tried to build apk it gives me an error. If I remove what I added to `android/app/src/main/res/drawable-night` I can build apk successfully

Answer (score 2):

In your project folder's `android/app/src/main/res` there should be a drawable folder, which contains the `launch_background.xml` for light theme. Duplicate this folder and call the second one `drawable-night` and configure the dark theme style. It will automatically change based on Android's system theme.

The `launch_background.xml` in the `drawable` (light theme) folder can be structured as so, to display an image with a white background:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/launch_image" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Here are some sources,[Here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/splash-screens-for-dark-and-light-mode-in-flutter-eb85f1aa025#:%7E:text=dart%2C%20add%20the%20following%20line,how%20the%20app%20looks%20now.) and
[Source](https://medium.com/flutter-community/splash-screens-for-dark-and-light-mode-in-flutter-eb85f1aa025#:%7E:text=dart%2C%20add%20the%20following%20line,how%20the%20app%20looks%20now.)